# Overriding theme_links__main_menu()

Tags: theming, routes

I have the following call in page.tpl.php.

```
 theme('links__main_menu',array(...));
```

How can I override the theme function that is being called from that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a theme, you just declare the `mytheme_links__main_menu()` function in the template.php file. (Replace `mytheme` with the actual name of the theme.)

In a module, you declare the `mymodule_links__main_menu()` function, and implement [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) to define the theme function. (Replace `mymodule` with the actual name of the module.)

The argument passed to the function are the same passed to [theme_links()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_links/7).

`$variables`: An associative array containing:

- links: An associative array of links to be themed. The key for each link is used as its CSS class. Each link should be itself an array, with the following elements:

  - title: The link text.
  - href: The link URL. If omitted, the 'title' is shown as a plain text item in the links list.
  - html: (optional) Whether or not 'title' is HTML. If set, the title will not be passed through `check_plain()`.
  - attributes: (optional) Attributes for the anchor, or for the  tag used in its place if no 'href' is supplied. If element 'class' is included, it must be an array of one or more class names.

  If the 'href' element is supplied, the entire link array is passed to `l()` as its `$options` parameter.

  - attributes: A keyed array of attributes for the UL containing the list of links.
  - heading: (optional) A heading to precede the links. May be an associative array or a string. If it's an array, it can have the following elements:

    1. text: The heading text.
    2. level: The heading level (e.g. 'h2', 'h3').
    3. class: (optional) An array of the CSS classes for the heading.

Answer (score 0):

This is a theme hook pattern of the form [base hook]_*[context]. When links are themed with theme('links*_main_menu', $vars), theme() will search for and use theme_links__main_menu() if it has been defined. If not, it will use theme_links().